# TreeSet and HashSet

Tags: java, collections, set, hashset, treeset

Why can't `HashSet` also be an answer for the following question? When I tested the code, both `HashSet` and `TreeSet` gave the same output, but the correct answer it seems is `TreeSet`. The code is below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // insert code here
        set.add(new Integer(2));
        set.add(new Integer(1));
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

> Which code, inserted at line 4, guarantees that this program will
>   output [1, 2]?
>
> 1. `Set set = new TreeSet();`
> 2. `Set set = new HashSet();`
> 3. `Set set = new SortedSet();`
> 4. `List set = new SortedList();`
> 5. `Set set = new LinkedHashSet();`

Comment: The chance of getting the answer to a boolean question right simply by guessing is surprisingly high…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashSet` is *unordered*, which specifically means that Java makes no guarantee about the order in which keys (and therefore values) are stored.  On the other hand, `TreeSet` stores its elements in a natural order.

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) for `TreeSet`:

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
>   and If the objects can not 
>   be sorted in natural order than use compareTo() method to sort the elements of TreeSet object but hashmap is using equals() method to compare the elements.

Comment: Noted. Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The choices are:

1. `Set set = new TreeSet();`

As per [doc](http://The%20elements%20are%20ordered%20using%20their%20natural%20ordering,%20or%20by%20a%20Comparator%20provided%20at%20set%20creation%20time,%20depending%20on%20which%20constructor%20is%20used.):

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a
>   Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.

So this is **correct answer** as after insertion natural ordering would be `[1,2]`.

2. `Set set = new HashSet();`
   `HashSet` is not ordered so no guarantee of natural ordering as well. This is not correct answer.
3. `Set set = new SortedSet();`
   SortedSet is an interface.
4. List set = new SortedList();
   That is definitely not correct answer for obvious reasons.
5. `Set set = new LinkedHashSet();`
   Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. In that case output would be `[2,1]`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. `Set set = new TreeSet();`

Yes as `TreeSet` is a sorted set and natural order for keys `2` and `1` is `1`, `2`.

> 2. `Set set = new HashSet();`

No as `HashSet` does not guarantee any order.

> 3. `Set set = new SortedSet();`

Compilation error: `SortedSet` is an interface and cannot be instantiated.

> 4. `List set = new SortedList();`

Compilation error: there's no standard `SortedList` class in Java.

> 5. `Set set = new LinkedHashSet();`

The order is guaranteed to be `2` and `1` (insertion order).